# Calling a procedure by pointer from variable in Intel 8086 Assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, call, procedure, x86-16

Let's say I have a variable with procedure address:

```
func_pointer dw offset my_function

my_function proc near

my_function endp
```

How can I call it from the variable?

I have tried

```
call dword ptr[func_pointer + 1]
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: 8086 in 16 bits, or x86-64, or i686? And what ABI? What system? Do you have a C compiler? If yes, code a similar function in C and look into the generated assembler code (e.g. `gcc -Wall -O1 -fverbose-asm -S`)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. It's on Intel 8086 in 16 bits

Comment: Which ABI? Which operating system (or BIOS)? And please edit your own question (but don't comment it)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know ABI is. I am using DosBox to run the code

Comment: **Read** about [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), [Calling Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) then **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's not obvious that any ABI would apply here. Assembly code only needs to follow an ABI when it interfaces with another language that does.

Comment: But a calling convention does apply. 8086 has no native single instruction to call a function with arguments

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - is it not the case that again, the ABI is not necessarily relevant? How does your assertion that it is important work in the case that the function takes no arguments and returns no result?A `void myFunc()`, if you will? Certainly, the ABI _may_ be important, but are you able to say with confidence and the available info in the question, that the ABI _is_ important in this case? If I'm missing something, I'd prefer not to in the future.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is use `call func_pointer` or `call [func_pointer]` (they're both the same to MASM). Because the type of the symbol `func_pointer` is WORD the assembler knows to use an indirect call rather than a direct call.

For example:

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT PUBLIC USE16
    ASSUME DS:_TEXT

func_pointer dw offset my_function

my_function proc near
    ret
my_function endp

caller proc
    call [func_pointer]
caller endp

_TEXT   ENDS

    END
```

Comment: I tried that, TASM compiler says: Near jump or call to different CS

Comment: IMO, if you *can* use `call [func_ptr]` for an indirect call, you should, because it's less confusing, and you don't have to keep it in your head that the symbol name is a function pointer, not a function.  It's also the only valid syntax in NASM (for that reason: it doesn't try to figure out what you mean from how you defined a symbol).  If NASM supported `mov reg, OFFSET symbol`, I'd recommend always using that syntax for encoding `mov reg, imm` when that's what you mean, again so your idiom of choice does the same thing on MASM and NASM.  Unfortunately OFFSET isn't a NASM keyword.

Comment: @HarisVitunskas The example I posted in my answer assembles without error with both TASM 3.1 and TASM 5.0.